# Can't use multiple docker networks in a swarm at the same time

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, cloud, docker-swarm

I made a docker swarm with 2 overlay networks (backend and frontend), I have two swarm services one connected to the backend network and the other connected to the frontend. 
Both are web apps running on different ports, 80 and 5001. 
If I do `curl localhost:80` or `curl localhost:5001` they both work fine but if I try to access them through the browser with an external IP only the service that I ran earlier would work. 
 
i.e if I do `docker service create -p 80:80 frontend` and then `docker service create -p 5001:80 backend` only the frontend works with an external ip the other only works internally, and vice versa if I start the backend first only that would work... 
Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?
Other may be relevant details: 
Running the swarm on google cloud on Ubuntu machines.

Comment: You will need to use load balancer in that scenario, this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/docker-swarm-on-google-cloud-platform-c9925bd7863c) might help. https://medium.com/google-cloud/docker-swarm-on-google-cloud-platform-c9925bd7863c

Comment: Please confirm if I am understanding. You have two services based on containers which both expose themself (the containers, not the swarm services) on port 80. If you run a single docker service create -p 80:80 frontend or docker service create -p 5001:80 backend, the corresponding curl localhost:80 or curl localhost:5001 works.